# Retrieving useful node data from SLURM?

Tags: slurm

I just wondered if anyone had a written a command to process the output of "scontrol shows nodes" into something more legible, e.g qhost in SGE which gives you a table in the following format: Node, NCPU, Load, Memtotal, Memuse, State, Partition, Jobs

I have a similar command with PBS that transforms PBSNODES into this format but I haven't found one for SLURM.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Slurm ships with a `slurm-torque` package that offers the `pbsnodes` command, so you could use your existing script with `pbsnodes`.

Otherwise, some people have shared useful scripts for parsing Slurm commands:

- https://github.com/birc-aeh/slurm-utils
- https://github.com/OleHolmNielsen/Slurm_tools